# appendTo does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code

```js
$('#fancybox-wrap .caption').appendTo('#fancybox-outer #fancybox-content');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="fancybox-wrap">
    <div id="fancybox-outer">
        <div id="fancybox-content"></div>
    </div>
    <p class="caption">Hello world</p>
</div>
```

I want to put `.caption` into `#fancybox-content`.
I try to append this p but it does not work

Thanks for the help !

Comment: I don't see `.wp-caption-text`

Comment: Still don't see in `HTML`

Comment: Can you create `jsfiddle`?

Comment: Here it is http://jsfiddle.net/9ajt6ctp/

Comment: The `jsfiddle` works perfectly. Show the resulting `HTML` you want

Answer (score 0):

You don't use any class named wp-caption-text in the fancybox-wrap div. You have to change the classname when you access the object :

```
$('#fancybox-wrap .caption').appendTo('#fancybox-outer #fancybox-content');
```

Or change the class attribute in your p element :

```
<p class="wp-caption-text">Hello world</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

are you trying to add .caption class to #fancybox-outer #fancybox-content ? .. in that case i would suggest you use..

```
$('#fancybox-outer').addClass('caption');
$('#fancybox-content').addClass('caption');
```

instead of the appendTo...

Comment: I want the <p> move into #fancybox-content

Comment: @CorentinBranquet try this `$('#fancybox-content').append($('.caption').html());`

Comment: you can clear the `$('.caption').html('');` if you dont need it after the contents are copied